# Regex in Javascript; string between last and one before last "/"

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

How to get "foo19" out of the following string

```
"C:\Users\test\AppData\Roaming\test2\storage\foo19\text.txt"
```

lastIndexOf does not help in this case either; I just want "foo19" which happens between two "\"s the last "\" and the one before last "\". Is it possible with regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `foo19` is always the 2nd to last entry:

```
var str = "C:\\Users\\test\\AppData\\Roaming\\test2\\storage\\foo19\\text.txt";
var parts = str.split("\\");
var foo19 = parts[parts.length - 2];
```

Comment: Please just correct it with :var foo19 = parts[parts.length - 2]);

Answer (score 1):

Here is a regex that capture foo19 in a group, so access with $1.

```
.*\\(\w*)\\\w*.txt
```

The proof is [here](https://regex101.com/r/eC7tC5/1)